# Azure File Shares

Tags: azure, azure-storage, fileshare

I am really struggling on how to access the "secondary" replica of our file share storage. At present we are using an Azure File Share which is working well i.e. \storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\apps\ . The username is then \storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\storageaccountname and the password is one of two keys which works fine. If I try to access the replica copy of the above using \storageaccountname-secondary.file.core.windows.net\apps\ . I get asked for authentication so it must be seeing the location path but the username and or password don't work. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because Azure File Service doesn't support RAGRS thus you won't be able to read from secondary location.

Please read question 7 here under File Storage FAQ section: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/.